# GCP, despite existing forwarding rule no external IP on IIS

Tags: iis, google-compute-engine

I have a virutal windows server machine running on GCP.

On that machine I have an IIS with several web sites.

Untill recent windows update and restart in Site Binding I was able to see the external IP from the forwarding rule, like this:

[Example from another, working server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQQ1h.png)

But now the external IP is not listed, despite the forwarding rule exists:

[The real state of the server in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMBPx.png)

And because of this my sites are not working.

I've tried to deleting and creating forwarding rules via GCP Shell using `gcloud compute forwarding-rules delete ...` and `gcloud compute forwarding-rules create ...` to no avail.

With and without restarts after executing each of these commands or ageter both in a row.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I swear, I had "Hi all" line in the beginning. Don't know why it's not there now.
Anyhow, Hi all.

Comment: which kind of external IP address you have Ephemeral or Static? you could refer this link for more detail:[link1](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/basic-webserver-iis) ,[link2](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses) ,[link3](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/protocol-forwarding),[link4](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address)

Comment: Hi Jalpa, I have Static addresses.

Comment: I've reviewed the links provided by @JalpaPanchal - none of them really helps to get external IPs back to the IIS. :-(

Comment: Does working server have the same updates installed as non-working? Please provide more details about versions of OS and IIS installed on both servers.

Comment: Hi Serhii,  yes, both servers are WS2016 and both have same set of updates installed.

Comment: could you please share your os build information and which kb update you installed?

Comment: The problem was resolved with GCP support.
There's a service GCEAgent (Google Compute Engine Agent). It was stopped despite its startup type is automatic.
Starting the service brought all forwarded IP addresses back to IIS site binding window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved with GCP support. 
There's a service GCEAgent (Google Compute Engine Agent). 
It was stopped despite its startup type is automatic. 
Starting the service brought all forwarded IP addresses back to IIS site binding window.